# How to update a top level column based on nested field value in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, updates

I am trying to update a top level column based on a nested column value using case statements as below

```
UPDATE
  `project.database.table`
SET
  ReplaceTotal= (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.MessageCode='MO' AND DamageLineInfo.AutomatedEntry=TRUE AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OPO' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborType='LAB' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborInclInd=FALSE THEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborAmt
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP9'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP11'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP5'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP12'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP10'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP1'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP21' THEN
    CASE
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborType='LAB' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborInclInd=FALSE THEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborAmt
  END
  END as ReplaceTotal
  FROM
    UNNEST(ServiceBusEnvelope.Payload.RepairOrderFolderAddRq.DamageLineInfo) AS DamageLineInfo)
WHERE
  TRUE
```

I get the below error when i run the query
Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Help me understand the error.
If the error is because the data generated is having list of values, then please me get the first value of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the error is because the data generated is having list of values

Yes, this is the reason

> get the first value of the data

Just simply add `LIMIT 1` as in below example

```
UPDATE
  `project.database.table`
SET
  ReplaceTotal= (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.MessageCode='MO' AND DamageLineInfo.AutomatedEntry=TRUE AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OPO' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborType='LAB' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborInclInd=FALSE THEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborAmt
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP9'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP11'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP5'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP12'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP10'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP1'
    OR DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborOperation='OP21' THEN
    CASE
      WHEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborType='LAB' AND DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborInclInd=FALSE THEN DamageLineInfo.LaborInfo.LaborAmt
  END
  END as ReplaceTotal
  FROM
    UNNEST(ServiceBusEnvelope.Payload.RepairOrderFolderAddRq.DamageLineInfo) AS DamageLineInfo
  LIMIT 1
  )
WHERE
  TRUE
```

Comment: I am trying to write BQ query based on JOLT transformation already exist. Please help how to convert jolt transformation to BQ without manual intervention